# Image in google maps v3 infowWindow loading twice

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i try to display an image inside an infoWindow. Nothing special about it, but when the infoWindow is opened, the content is loaded twice. when i replace the the `<img>` tag with some text, everything is fine. 
i retrieve the html-content of the infoWindow via ajax before setting the content and displaying it. this call is only done once (firebug tells me so). but the 'domready' event of the infoWindow gets called twice. what is the problem with the image inside the infoWindow?

here's the html of the infoWindow:

```
<img class="content-image" src="./content/image/1.jpg" width="450" heigth="400">
```

are there any events besides the `domready` i could listen to after calling infoWindow.open() ?

Comment: can you please post some more related code or a demo?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem and concluded that the Google Maps API triggers a domready event when images trigger their load event.

*Also figured that the domready isn't fired twice when using background image*

My solution : I don't trust the infowindow domready event anymore, and I use the success callback of my request that gives me the infowindow content

NB

**Infowindow event list :**

- closeclick : This event is fired when the close button was clicked.
- content_changed  This event is fired when the content property
  changes.
- domready : This event is fired when the  containing the
  InfoWindow's content is attached to the DOM. You may wish to monitor
  this event if you are building out your info window content
  dynamically.
- position_changed : This event is fired when the position
  property changes.
- zindex_changed : This event is fired when the
  InfoWindow's zIndex changes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution, by putting code into your answer? Thanks